# ¿Cómo hacer un recuento de una columna de datos en función de valores de otra en Python?

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un recuento de datos guardados en un df=pd.read_csv('datos.csv') que se parecen a esto:

```
Tipo  Duración
A     12
B     2
C     5
B     4
B     6
A     1
C     3
```

Me gustaría sacar la media de la duración del tipo A, B y C para posteriormente hacer un histograma con los datos. Si alguien puede ayudarme se agradece!

Answer (score 3):

Puedes sacar la media de cada tipo usando `groupby` y `mean`:

```
medias = df.groupby('Tipo')['Duración'].mean()
```

Este produce:

```
Tipo
A    6.5
B    4.0
C    4.0
Name: Duración, dtype: float64
```

Luego has dicho que quieres hacer un histograma, pero me parece mejor hacer una diagrama de barras para visualizar las medias:

```
medias.plot.bar()
```

Este produce:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]